# Parsing XML via jQuery, nested loops

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I am using jQuery to parse XML on my page using `$.ajax()`. My code block is below and I can get this working to display say each result on the XML file, but I am having trouble because each section can have MORE THAN ONE `<course>` and im trying to print ALL grades that belong to ONE STUDENT. Here is an example of the XML.

```
<student num="505">
    <name gender="male">Al Einstein</name>
    <course cid="1">60</course>
    <course cid="2">60</course>
    <course cid="3">40</course>
    <course cid="4">55</course>
    <comments>Lucky if he makes it to lab, hopeless.</comments>
</student>
```

Where you see the `<course>` I am trying to get the results to print the grades for EACH student in each course. Any ideas on what I would do?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "final_exam.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var student_list = $('#student-list');
                $(xml).find('student').each(function(){
                    $(xml).find('course').each(function(){
                        gradeArray = $(this).text();
                        console.log(gradeArray);
                    });
                    var name = $(this).find("name").text();
                    var grade = $(this).find("course").text();
                    var cid = $(this).find("course").attr("cid");

                    //console.log(cid);
                    student_list.append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+cid+"</td><td>"+grade+"</td></tr>");
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

On this line: `$(xml).find('course').each(function(){`

Did you mean to `find` off of `xml` or should that be `$(this).find`?

Comment: It should be:$(this).find - But that still doesn't seem to fix it. Its basically: ONE student can have MANY grades. And im trying to display that..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you are looking for this. All I did was capture grades in an array and join them via comma at the end. I also did not test (evil).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "final_exam.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var student_list = $('#student-list');
        $(xml).find("student").each(function(){

            var name = $(this).find("name").text();
            var grades = [];
            var cid = $(this).find("course").attr("cid");

            $(this).find('course').each(function(){
                var grade = $(this).text();
                console.log(gradeArray);
                grades[ grades.length ] = grade
            });

            //console.log(cid);

            student_list.append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+cid+"</td><td>"+grades.join(', ')+"</td></tr>");
        });
    }
});
```